# Could not initialize class sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI

Tags: java, java-web-start, noclassdeffounderror

We have client-server application and we launch the client application using java web start.

While trying to open client application, it first reads a token file from https url (for SSO) and later opens another HTTPS url.

tokenUrl = new URL(protocol, nodeIpAddress, port, tokenFile);
URLConnection con = tokenUrl.openConnection();

The openConnection() is throwing below Exception:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.mscapi.SunMSCAPI

Could any one please help what is the exact issue here and please provide necessary workarounds.

Thanks,
Sourav

Comment: Could you check whether sunmscapi.jar is in classpath

Comment: Yes it is present in jre. jre6 contains both the jar and dll file

Answer (score 1):

That class is an implemention of the Microsoft Crypto API, and it was added to the JRE only in Java 6 - so I suspect that it's a JRE version issue.

Comment: We are using jre 1.6.0_20 where the mscapi.jar and dll file is present in jre. We did not set any specific provider preference. java.policy itself contains the MSCapi provider entry